# postgres C:: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, permission-denied

I'm using Windows 10, and cmd psql. I'm following a tutorial on PostgreSQL, where I'm trying to import my ai-generated **.sql** file into previously created database named **test**. I use `\i  c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\person.sql` command. But i keep getting **C:: Permission denied** error.

I tried couple of things to resolve this issue. Firstly, i changed **permissions** in **Security** settings of the file and give **Everyone** - **full control**, which did not help. Then there were suggestions to simply format the path string in a particular way, which i did (see below) and no luck either.

`\i c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\person.sql`
i got:
`c:: Permission denied`

`\i c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql`
i got:
`c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql: No such file or directory`

`\i 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql'`
i got:
`C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql: No such file or directory`

`\i 'c:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\person.sql'`
i got:
`c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql: No such file or directory`

`\i C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\person.sql`
i got:
`C:: Permission denied`

I moved it to D drive, changed permissions and still got the same `D:: Permission denied` message. I run cmd as Admin, didn't help. I'm not sure what to do next?? I'm completely lost. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: The "no such file" error suggests a problem in the path. It's clearly not a permission error because you're getting that previously

Comment: i tried to solve the permission error by changing slashes in file path, as it was suggested here to others and worked for them. But for some reason changing slashes don't work anymore. My problem still is permission error.

Answer (score 3):

You've just run into a peculiarity of `psql` on Windows.

I just wanted to exclude the possibility that you really didn't have the necessary permission. Then it turned out that even on Windows, you have to use 'normal' slashes instead of backslashes, that is:

> `\i 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql'`
> should work fine regardless which folder you start `psql` from. Notice that I used single quotes - with double quotes you'd got

`"C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql": Invalid argument`

Comment: I used single quotes, as it is in the third option above in my post.  I didn't use double quotes.  That one didn't work at all. No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you guys after i uninstalled postgreSQL, and installed again the command with forward slashes in single quotes  `\i 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/person.sql'` worked!!! So, if you have similar problem try to delete postgresql and then install it again.

Comment: While that may have worked for you -- that really isn't an answer (yes, that IS what you did), but basically it simply relied on the happenstance of the reinstall and the change from DOS to normal directory separators. The old "try a reboot" or "try a reinstall" has been a DOS/windows hallmark since Bill blessed/cursed us with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Forward Slash (/) in Paths:**

In the psql shell on Windows, you can use forward slashes (/) instead of backslashes () in file paths. For example:

```
\i C:/path/to/your/file.sql
```